# Test class code coverage 2%

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest public class ContactTriggerHandlerTest {
    @isTest static void contactTriggerHandlerTest2(){
        Boolean exceptionThrown = false;
        try{
            Contact c1 = new Contact();
            c1.LastName = 'ABC';
            c1.test = 'xyz';
            c1.Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2019, 11, 20);
            c1.End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2019, 11, 24);
            insert c1;
            Contact c2 = new Contact();
            c1.test = 'xyz';
            c2.LastName = 'ABC';
            c2.Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2019, 11, 21);
            c2.End_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2019, 11, 26);
            insert c2;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            exceptionThrown = true;
            Boolean expectedExceptionThrown = (e.getMessage().contains('You cannot overlap dates in same Contact')) ? true : false; 
            System.AssertEquals(true, expectedExceptionThrown, e.getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Your question's been linked to our standard resources on code coverage - please give them a read as they'll likely solve your problem. If you're still struggling, you're welcome to open a new question, but please be very specific about a line or lines you're struggling to cover and include the relevant code.

Comment: If it doesn't help, we can't help without seeing the class being tested. You should [edit] your question to include it and go over what you've applied from that canonical-qa question. You also have a copy/paste error (`c1.test` is being set when you are trying to set up your `c2` contact).